# Replace Zeros Bounded Between Ones in a List

Tags: python, list, slice

Suppose I have a list as shown below. How could you iterate over the list and replace the zeros bounded between ones where the length of zeros in between can vary?

Input:

```
mylist = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

Output:

```
mylist = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]
```

Comment: Why are there still zeros in the middle?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You seem to have answered your own question. Mind explaining a bit as I still don't exactly understand?

Comment: @ChristianDean: It's like the *even-odd* rule in graphics: there is a "burst" of ones, a burst of "zeros", etc. So we fill with ones between the first two ones, the third and the fourth 1, and so on.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, I got you. Thanks.

Comment: Can the input list contain adjacent ones? eg. `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]`. If so, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do this in two phases:

1. first we obtain the indices where the ones are indicates; and
2. we take two ones at a time, and fill these all with ones.

Like:

```
# obtain an iterable of the indices of the ones
ones = iter([i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x == 1])

# for every pair of indices
for i0,i1 in zip(ones,ones):
    # iterate over the range
    for j in range(i0+1,i1):
        # and assign 1 to these indices
        mylist[j] = 1
```

This generates:

```
>>> mylist
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the flag, wherever you're "inside" 1-1 block (and u need to update 0 to 1) or not.

This assumes, that single ("last") 1 will produce ones till the end of the list:

```
inside = False
for x in range(len(data)):
  if data[x]:
    inside = not inside
  elif inside:
    data[x] = 1
[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ] -> [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ] -> [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

If it was not what you want and last 1 should be ignored:

```
start_block = None
for x in range(len(data)):
  if data[x]:
    if start_block is not None:
      for y in range(start_block + 1, x):
        data[y] = 1
      start_block
    else: 
      start_block = x
[ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ] -> [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ] -> [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
```